# Suggestions for building a clothing exchange site with Joomla/virtuemart

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, e-commerce, virtuemart

I  want  to build a website to allow users  exchange clothes with  each other.The website will be similar to an online auction site and a book exchange. This will be a point-based exchange community. The website allows users to

1) register for a private account

2) list items based on a specific, yet simple form that they can keep track of in their account

3) Rate items that they have received based on three simple criteria

4)  Admin  can  add/delete  products and  also  categorise  them

5) Sizes labels  etc can be  assigned  to products

6) Other  users can  upload  their  products/categorize  them assign

7)  users  can perform faceted  search on the products  and  filter  by  size, label etc..

**One main point here is that  there is  no  payment  involved.**  I  was thinking to use  virtuemart over joomla for  this  kinda  website and  needed  an opinion on how  tough would it be customize virtuemart/joomla to  meet the  requirements.

Can you  please  suggest some other architecture if you  think that the above arechitecture  is not  feasible to build  this sorta  website? Magento is  not  an  option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely people need be able to exchange items?  From taking a quick look at your specification, I don't think your list covers all of the required functionality.

While cash payment isn't required, it sounds like payment might be involved because your site is a 'point-based exchange community'.  I think this might actually make the task of creating your site slightly more complicated because there's less chance of using pre-written modules (most e-commerce CMSs are geared towards cash payments).

I'd suggest you look at an ecommerce system called Ubercart (which is based on Drupal).  This can be customised reasonably easily by writing modules which plug-in to the main CMS.  There's also a very supportive developer community.  To work out the feasibility of using Ubercart, I'd recommend posting your question on the Ubercart forum (www.ubercart.org).

Comment: Well.. Ubercart  is  same as what virtuemart  is for joomla. Could you please  comment  on if ubercart  would be feasible and easy enough for  such a site? and yeah the cash wont be introduced for quite a long time  as  well since the only  way users  can earn points for  now is by uploading/getting  rated  and use  those  earned points to buy clothes.

Comment: Personally, I like Ubercart a lot .. the Drupal module system is quite intuitive once you get the hang of it.  I think 'easy enough' is very much relative to the person doing the developing, but I think almost any developer can progress very quickly due to the large community and associated blogs / documentation.